# How to use BigDecimal in swing GUIs?

Tags: java, swing, bigdecimal

I'm using BigDecimal to represent product prices in a Java SE application.

What swing component(s) should I use in order to allow the user to input numbers with only two decimal places and bound it to a BigDecimal variable/Object's property. (Checking that as the user types)?

I've been playing with JTextField, JFormattedTextField, NumberFormatter, MaskFormatter but I can't work it out.

Is there any combination and configuration of those components to do that? or should I extend the MaskFormatter, the JTextField, ...?

Answer (score 2):

I hate to necro these really old threads on stuff, but my understanding is StackOverflow cries inside every day an answer remains unsolved.

so you can checkout the code here: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/ABigDecimalobjectcustomformatter.htm

basically set-up to a JFormattedTextField to use a DecimalFormat

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what you are trying to do, but there is a BigDecimal constructor which takes Strings as parameter (similar to e.g. `Double.parseDouble(String s)`):

```
try
{
    BigDecimal decimal = new BigDecimal(yourJTextField.getText());
}
catch (NumberFormatException nfe)
{ /* error handling */}
```

See JavaDoc for [BigDecimal](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal%28java.lang.String%29) for more information.

**Edit:** If checking/validating the user's input into the textfield, either check it manually or use a Validator (see [Google results for "JTextField Validator"](http://www.google.de/search?q=jtextfield+validator))

Comment: The problems is that I want a component that only allows numbers, and only allows 2 decimal places on it: if the user types a letter, it's not shown, if the user types a third decimal place, it's not shown. On top of that I want to bound that component to a BigDecimal variable.

Comment: Have a look at the InputVerifier doc then: http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/InputVerifier.html

Comment: The InputVerifier acts when the focus changes. I want to control the input as the user types in the component.

Comment: You could, of course, simply use the CaretPositionChanged Event for TextFields, check what the user has entered, if it's valid, don't do anything, if it's invalid remove the last typed character.