# Edit on focus JPanel inside JTable

Tags: swing, focus, jtable, jpanel

this question is similar to:
[Problem getting focus when use JPanel as JTable cell editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3986074/problem-getting-focus-when-use-jpanel-as-jtable-cell-editor)

Only I seem to be stuck one step back.

I have a custom TableCellEditor that returns a JPanel with a JTextField inside (simplified case).
I want the JTextField to be edited when I tab into that table cell.

I have this piece of code in my JTable, in order to make the table edit on tab:

```
public void changeSelection(final int row, int column, boolean toggle, boolean extend){
        System.out.println("selectionChanged");
    super.changeSelection(row, column, toggle, extend);
    if (!isCellEditable(row, column))
        return;
    AuthorTableEditor editor = (AuthorTableEditor) getCellEditor(row, column);
    editor.setAutoFocus(this, row, column);
    editCellAt(row, column);
}
```

The setAutoFocus is used so the methods in the AuthorTableEditor will not be called twice.

How do I get the JTextField to be edited, like what happens when I just return a JTextField in the TableCellEditor?

Comment: no way to help without seeing the custom editor (and an sscce, to make it easy to actually test :-)