# Java Swing - a good textfield component for numbers?

Tags: java, user-interface, swing

i am bit new to java and swing so... 
 can someone please tell me how to utilize swing textfield component for number processing  (money, decimal...) ?
 or can someone tell me where to find swing component witch is designed for this ?
 I am building a small ERP app, and standard Swing or SwingX simple do not have a good number processing
 component)

(FormattedTextField is no good!)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2511415

Comment: -1,Well, what exactly are your requirements? If JFormattedTextField is no good what are the problems and what do you expect to be done differently?

Answer (score 5):

[JSpinner](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/JSpinner.html) is designed for numbers. But what kind of number processing do you need from the component?

Answer (score 2):

I've implemented number fields based on JFormattedTextField.

They also support a min and a max value.

Maybe you find them useful (the library is open source):

http://softsmithy.sourceforge.net/lib/docs/api/org/softsmithy/lib/swing/JRealNumberField.html

http://softsmithy.sourceforge.net/lib/docs/api/org/softsmithy/lib/swing/JDoubleField.html

http://softsmithy.sourceforge.net/lib/docs/api/org/softsmithy/lib/swing/JFloatField.html

http://softsmithy.sourceforge.net/lib/docs/api/org/softsmithy/lib/swing/JLocalizedRealNumberField.html

http://softsmithy.sourceforge.net/lib/docs/api/org/softsmithy/lib/swing/JLocalizedDoubleField.html

http://softsmithy.sourceforge.net/lib/docs/api/org/softsmithy/lib/swing/JLocalizedFloatField.html

http://softsmithy.sourceforge.net/lib/docs/api/org/softsmithy/lib/swing/JWholeNumberField.html

http://softsmithy.sourceforge.net/lib/docs/api/org/softsmithy/lib/swing/JByteField.html

http://softsmithy.sourceforge.net/lib/docs/api/org/softsmithy/lib/swing/JIntegerField.html

http://softsmithy.sourceforge.net/lib/docs/api/org/softsmithy/lib/swing/JLongField.html

http://softsmithy.sourceforge.net/lib/docs/api/org/softsmithy/lib/swing/JShortField.html

Homepage:

http://www.softsmithy.org

Download:

http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=64833

Tutorial:
http://softsmithy.sourceforge.net/lib/docs/tutorial/swing/number/index.html

-Puce

Comment: Your project code is browsable via Subversion, but an apparently empty Mercurial repository is also enabled in the Project Admin menu. It might bear checking.

Comment: Hi trashgod,
yes, I know, I'm currently in the process of migrating svn to Mercurial. Nobody is checking in something on Subversion currently and it will probably stay there as read-only (so links don't break).

Comment: you really need to check out generics and object-oriented patterns like abstractions, code reuse and stuff.

Comment: @tulskiy: No, I don't need to "check out generics" - I just need to find time to upgrade the library. I started the project back in 2002 - Java didn't support generics at that time.
I think I'm quite familiar with OO patterns like abstractions, code reuse etc., though some code in that library is quite old. Which parts were you refering to?

Answer (score 0):

You can keep a listener to check the content being entered and validate accordingly..

[Here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/Textfieldonlyacceptsnumbers.htm) is an example

Comment: @Virtuo How about http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-Components/differentconfigurationsofJFormattedTextFieldNumber.htm

Comment: @Virtuo: make it a custom component and it will be OK on a project level.