# How to use BigDecimal with JFormattedTextField

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, bigdecimal, jformattedtextfield

I have a field as:

```
jFormattedTextFieldGrossWeight = new javax.swing.JFormattedTextField();
jFormattedTextFieldGrossWeight.setFormatterFactory(new javax.swing.text.DefaultFormatterFactory(new javax.swing.text.NumberFormatter(new java.text.DecimalFormat("#,##0.00"))));
```

I assign it a BigDecimal value using its setValue() method, and allow the user to modify that value using this textfield.

Then in the lostFocus method, on the line:

```
jFormattedTextField.commitEdit();
BigDecimal gross = (BigDecimal)this.jFormattedTextFieldGrossWeight.getValue();
```

I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.math.BigDecimal
```

Is there anything wrong? How can I modify my code to get rid of this error?

Comment: For a use in a `JTable` context, see [`DecEditor`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2511270/advice-welcomed-on-creating-my-own-swing-component/2511415#2511415), which permits `BigDecimal` in a `DefaultCellEditor`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this:

```
JFormattedTextField ftf = new JFormattedTextField();
ftf.setFormatterFactory(new DefaultFormatterFactory(
                        new NumberFormatter(new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00"))));


// Input = 1245678.57
// After the format it will be:
// 1,245,678.57
// So, we need to get rid of the comma's:
String number = ftf.getText().replace(",","");
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(number);
```

Comment: @Statue http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html and examples for tutorial http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/Formatted-TextField.htm

Answer (score 3):

I've implemented number fields based on JFormattedTextField.

JRealNumberField and JLocalizedRealNumberField are text fields for BigDecimal.

They also support a min and a max value.

Maybe you find them useful (the library is open source):

http://softsmithy.sourceforge.net/lib/docs/api/org/softsmithy/lib/swing/JRealNumberField.html

http://softsmithy.sourceforge.net/lib/docs/api/org/softsmithy/lib/swing/JDoubleField.html

http://softsmithy.sourceforge.net/lib/docs/api/org/softsmithy/lib/swing/JFloatField.html

http://softsmithy.sourceforge.net/lib/docs/api/org/softsmithy/lib/swing/JLocalizedRealNumberField.html

http://softsmithy.sourceforge.net/lib/docs/api/org/softsmithy/lib/swing/JLocalizedDoubleField.html

http://softsmithy.sourceforge.net/lib/docs/api/org/softsmithy/lib/swing/JLocalizedFloatField.html

http://softsmithy.sourceforge.net/lib/docs/api/org/softsmithy/lib/swing/JWholeNumberField.html

http://softsmithy.sourceforge.net/lib/docs/api/org/softsmithy/lib/swing/JByteField.html

http://softsmithy.sourceforge.net/lib/docs/api/org/softsmithy/lib/swing/JIntegerField.html

http://softsmithy.sourceforge.net/lib/docs/api/org/softsmithy/lib/swing/JLongField.html

http://softsmithy.sourceforge.net/lib/docs/api/org/softsmithy/lib/swing/JShortField.html

Tutorial:

http://softsmithy.sourceforge.net/lib/docs/tutorial/swing/number/index.html

Homepage:

http://www.softsmithy.org

Download:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/softsmithy/files/softsmithy/

Maven:

```
<dependency>  
    <groupid>org.softsmithy.lib</groupid>  
    <artifactid>lib-core</artifactid>  
    <version>0.1</version>  
</dependency>
```

-Puce