# Probability cell editor

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have class `Probability`. I want use custom renderer for it (already done) and double like editor. But I can't even find double editor (only Number), so I really have no idea how I should implement it. The question is: how I should implement it?

*difference from double editor: it should permit only numbers in range `0..100`

Comment: First could you explain what a "double editor" is?

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels, it is `TableCellEditor` that permits input doubles in jtable's cells

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about a `JFormattedTextField` with an AbstractFormatter doing the conversion, and a DocumentFilter to reject anything which is not a valid percentage value?

Here is an example DocumentFilter (not tested, from reading the documentation):

```
class PercentageFilter extends DocumentFilter {
    insertString(FilterBypass bp, int offset, String adding, AttributeSet attrs) {
        Document doc = bp.getDocument();
        String text = doc.getText(0, offset) + adding + doc.getText(offset, doc.getLength()-offset);
        try {
            double d = Double.parseDouble(text);
            if(d < 0 || 100 < d) {
                // to big or too small number
                return;
            }
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException ex) {
            // invalid number, do nothing.
            return;
        }
        // if we come to this point, the entered number
        // is a valid value => really insert it into the document.
        bp.insertString(offset, adding, attrs);
    }
}
```

You would want to override `remove()` and `replace` similarly.

(I suppose there could be a more efficient implementation, but this will be fast enough for most user's typing speed, I suppose.)

This filter would be returned from your AbstractFormatter implementation's `getDocumentFilter` method.

Comment: +1 [`DecEditor`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2511270/advice-welcomed-on-creating-my-own-swing-component/2511415#2511415) is an example.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works exactly as I wish for editing valid values. But I didn't get idea with `DocumentFilter`. How could I permit entering big numbers in this way?

Comment: @Stas: I added an example to the answer.

Answer (score 5):

> ..numbers in range 0..100

Use a `JSpinner` as the `TableCellEditor`.

Comment: Thanks. But unfortunately I don't think it will be useful in my case. It's not integers and users will input values manually by typing numbers.

Comment: I'm really confused, where is your fromBlueToPurple eye, +1 for good advice without sideEffects

Comment: @mKorbel: "where is your fromBlueToPurple eye" I was getting sick of that image.  After playing with [text clipping](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6295084/cut-out-image-in-shape-of-text/6296381#6296381) the other day, I thought I'd try and combine some letters into a single `Shape`.  A couple of `Area`s (& minutes) later, & I had the new image.  (tilts head) Not sure if I like it, yet.  ;)