# Custom Swing Component Model, Component, UI delegate

Tags: java, swing, model, custom-component

I am very new to java in general and especially using Swing. I have created a custom swing component that zooms in and out on a picture using a slider. However I am now required to make it so that my code represents three classes
• Model

• The   UI  delegate

• An    implementation  of  the component   to  bundle  the model and   UI  delegate
together

I am very lost and cannot seem to get the code to function properly when I begin splitting it up into different classes. I have the interface working when implemented in a single class. Any help on how best to retool this code so that it fits into the previously mentioned model would be greatly appreciated. Here is my code.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.event.*;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class CustomComponent extends JComponent implements ChangeListener {

JPanel gui;
JLabel imageCanvas;
Dimension size;
double scale = 1.0;
private BufferedImage image;

public CustomComponent() {
    size = new Dimension(10, 10);
    setBackground(Color.black);
    try {
         image = ImageIO.read(new File("car.jpg"));
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void setImage(Image image) {
    imageCanvas.setIcon(new ImageIcon(image));
}

public void initComponents() {
    if (gui == null) {
        gui = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        gui.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        imageCanvas = new JLabel();
        JPanel imageCenter = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        imageCenter.add(imageCanvas);
        JScrollPane imageScroll = new JScrollPane(imageCenter);
        imageScroll.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 100));
        gui.add(imageScroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
}

public Container getGui() {
    initComponents();
    return gui;
}

public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
    int value = ((JSlider) e.getSource()).getValue();
    scale = value / 100.0;
    paintImage();
}

protected void paintImage() {

    int imageWidth = image.getWidth();
    int imageHeight = image.getHeight();
    BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(
            (int)(imageWidth*scale), 
            (int)(imageHeight*scale), 
            image.getType());
    Graphics2D g2 = bi.createGraphics();
    g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    AffineTransform at = AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(0, 0);
    at.scale(scale, scale);
    g2.drawRenderedImage(image, at);
    setImage(bi);
}

public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    int w = (int) (scale * size.width);
    int h = (int) (scale * size.height);
    return new Dimension(w, h);
}

private JSlider getControl() {
    JSlider slider = new JSlider(JSlider.HORIZONTAL, 1, 500, 50);
    slider.setMajorTickSpacing(50);
    slider.setMinorTickSpacing(25);
    slider.setPaintTicks(true);
    slider.setPaintLabels(true);
    slider.addChangeListener(this);
    return slider;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    CustomComponent app = new CustomComponent();
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setContentPane(app.getGui());
    app.setImage(app.image);

    // frame.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(app));  
    frame.getContentPane().add(app.getControl(), "Last");
    frame.setSize(700, 500);
    frame.setLocation(200, 200);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Comment: See [*How to Write a Custom Swing Component*](https://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/02/22/how-to-write-custom-swing-component.html), cited [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2511270/230513).